# Conversion from CMYK to RGB with Pillow is different from that of Photoshop

Tags: python, rgb, photoshop, python-imaging-library, image-conversion

I need to convert an image from CMYK to RGB in python. I used Pillow in this way:

```
img = Image.open('in.jpg')
img = img.convert('RGB')
img.save('out.jpg')
```

The code works, but if I convert the same image with Photoshop I have a different result as shown below:-

[image: a]

The only operation done in photoshop is to change method from CMYK to RGB.
Why there is this difference between the two RGB images? It can be a color profile problem?

Comment: Jgeg images always use [YCbCr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr) as [color format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Encoding) so this conversion is superfluous - it looks like photoshop knows this and doesnt touch the image but pillow naively compresses the image normally on saving (adding compression artifacts)

Comment: Also pillow possibly does not take an embedded [ICC profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICC_profile) into account changing the colors of the image a bit.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**SOLVED**

The problem is that Pillow does not know the input ICC profile, while photoshop had one set as default.

Photoshop use for

**CMYK**: U.S. Web Coated (SWOP) v2

**RGB**: sRGB IEC61966-2.1

So I've solved in this way:

```
img = Image.open('in.jpg')
img = ImageCms.profileToProfile(img, 'USWebCoatedSWOP.icc', 'sRGB Color Space Profile.icm', renderingIntent=0, outputMode='RGB')
img.save('out.jpg', quality=100)
```

---

On Windows the profiles can be found (if installed) in these folders:

```
C:\Windows\System32\spool\drivers\color\USWebCoatedSWOP.icc
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\Color\Profiles\Recommended\USWebCoatedSWOP.icc
C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat DC\Resource\Color\Profiles\Recommended\USWebCoatedSWOP.icc

C:\Windows\System32\spool\drivers\color\sRGB Color Space Profile.icm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\Color\Profiles\Recommended\sRGB Color Space Profile.icm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat DC\Resource\Color\Profiles\Recommended\sRGB Color Space Profile.icm
```

Comment: I'm getting "cannot open profile file" error. I guess, I need these profile `*.icc` files. Where do I find them?

Comment: I'm going to take liberty and add the paths to these profile files. Hope that's okay.

Comment: If you do not already have them, you can download the Adobe profiles here: https://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/iccprofiles/iccprofiles_win.html

Comment: Also, note that on macOS you can get pretty close with the generic CMYK profile (under `/System/Library/ColorSync/Profiles/Generic CMYK Profile.icc` on Catalina)