# How to create a cmyk image in python

Tags: python, image, cmyk

Is it possible to create a cmyk image using python like a rgb image?
suppose we have an 2d array and each element is a 4-dim vector! How can we convert it to a cmyk image?

Comment: What background work have you done to answer this question?

Comment: @aryamccarthy Unfortunately I am new user, so stack-overflow doesn't accept my vote at the moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you looked at the [Pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/index.html) library for images?

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.fromarray(A, mode="CMYK")
im.save("your_file.jpeg")
```

Answer (score 0):

You may discover any useful information in this doc

http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/handbook/tutorial.html

and this question

[Conversion from CMYK to RGB with Pillow is different from that of Photoshop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38855022/conversion-from-cmyk-to-rgb-with-pillow-is-different-from-that-of-photoshop)

Comment: thanks, but those link haven't answered this question!

Comment: 1. Answer is "Yes" - it is possible - and the docs will provide any necessary information for you to get it done. But to do something to transform your array is your job imho.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a python script named `ImageMode.py` in my Linux Ubuntu, the code is not optimized but it works well!

```
python3 ImageMode.py test.jpg
```

```
from PIL import Image
import sys

arg = sys.argv
if len(arg)==2:

   [file,ext] = str(arg[1]).split('.')
   image = Image.open(arg[1])

   if image.mode == 'CMYK':
       image = image.convert('RGB')

   elif image.mode == 'RGB':
       image = image.convert('CMYK')

   image.save(file+"_"+image.mode+"."+ext)

else:
   print("Argument missing")
```

If the image is RGB, then the output will be `test_CMYK.jpg`