# convert image to rgb array using PIL and manually convert it to CMYK array

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to convert an image to cmyk array manually and reconstruct the image but i didn't get any image then i decide to separate c,m,y,k and display it but there is no proper image .so i just tried to save every data in file for verification,i can't find any error in that data.can any one tell me why this happens and what is the error that i done here.i post my entire code below.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

im = Image.open('idcard.jpg').convert('RGB')
np_image = np.array(im)
num_list = np_image.tolist()
print( len(num_list))
str1 =str(num_list)
print( len(str1))
f=open("idcardforgb.txt","w")
f.write(str1)
f.close()

cyan = 0
magenta = 0
yellow = 0
key = 0
cmyk_scale = 255
t=np.shape(np_image)
print (t)
i=(int)(t[0])
j=(int)(t[1])
k=(int)(t[2])

c_final=[[[0 for f in range(4)]for g in range(j)]for h in range(i)]

for z in range(i):
    temp_z=z
    for y in range(j):
        temp_y=y
        for x in range(3):
            if x==0:
                r = np_image[z][y][x]
            if x==1:
                g = np_image[z][y][x]
            if x==2:
                 b = np_image[z][y][x]
        if (r == 0) and (g == 0) and (b == 0):
            cyan=0
            magenta=0
            yellow=0
            key=cmyk_scale
            c_final[temp_z][temp_y][0]=cyan
            c_final[temp_z][temp_y][1]=magenta
            c_final[temp_z][temp_y][2]=yellow
            c_final[temp_z][temp_y][3]=key
        else:
            c = 1 - r / 255.
            m = 1 - g / 255.
            y = 1 - b / 255.
            min_cmy = min(c,m,y)
            c = (c - min_cmy) / (1 - min_cmy)
            m = (m - min_cmy) / (1 - min_cmy)
            y = (y - min_cmy) / (1 - min_cmy)
            k = min_cmy
            cyan =(int) (c*cmyk_scale)
            magenta =(int) (m*cmyk_scale)
            yellow = (int)(y*cmyk_scale)
            key = (int)(k*cmyk_scale)

            c_final[temp_z][temp_y][0]=cyan
            c_final[temp_z][temp_y][1]=magenta
            c_final[temp_z][temp_y][2]=yellow
            c_final[temp_z][temp_y][3]=key

np_image1 = np.array(c_final)
t1=np.shape(np_image1)
print(t1)
cnum_list = np_image1.tolist()
print( len(cnum_list))
str1c =str(cnum_list)
print( len(str1c))
f=open("idcardcmyk.txt","w")
f.write(str1c)
f.close()
im = Image.fromarray(np_image1, mode='CMYK')
im.save('testing.jpg')
##im = Image.fromarray(im, mode="CMYK")
print("test ok")
ct = np_image1[:, :, 0]
cyan_list=ct.tolist()
str_c =str(cyan_list)
f=open("idcard_cp.txt","w")
f.write(str_c)
f.close()
print("test ok")
img= Image.fromarray(ct)
img.save('idcard_c.png')
mt = np_image1[:, :, 1]
imm= Image.fromarray(mt)
imm.save('idcard_m.png')
yt = np_image1[:, :, 2]
imm = Image.fromarray(yt)
imm.save('idcard_y.png')
kt = np_image1[:, :, 3]
imm = Image.fromarray(kt)
imm.save('idcard_k.png')
```

Comment: You should include the stack trace in this answer. Also where did you get the code for the RGB to CMYK conversion?

Comment: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14088375/how-can-i-convert-rgb-to-cmyk-and-vice-versa-in-python" conversion that i done based on the link.please tell me what is the error in this code